# UL/IEC-60950 Standard Question

Tags: standard, ul

One of the requirements I need for a device is to meet the UL/IEC-60950 standard. On the companies website I am looking at it mentions that "products are assembled and tested in company’s own ISO9001:2015 and IPC-A-610 certified facilities." What are the chances that this product meets the 60950?

(I have reached out to the company as well but just curious what the thoughts were of the community)

Comment: They have nothing do do with each other. Ask for their UL/IEC-60950 certificate for the product!

Answer (score 2):

These have nothing to do with one another. You don't learn anything regarding meeting 60950 from their claims.

ISO9001 has to do with internal quality management, and IPC-A-610 has to do with quality/acceptance of PCB assemblies.

UL/IEC-60950 is a safety testing requirement.

Comment: Wrong, correct, wrong and wrong.

Comment: Could you explain Barleyman? Admittedly I am not super familiar with the non-UL standards, so I'm curious where I went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer. IPC-A-610 is standard on PCB assembly, you need a supplier with relevant certificates to supply a safe product and IEC60950 is a top-level safety requirements specification, individual tests may be specified by referenced standards.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, however I spent 3 years working at UL on similar standards (not 60950, but other IEC 6-series standards) and we never asked about ISO9001 or IPC-A-610.

Comment: Also, my understanding is that the OP is asking about buying a finished Widget A from Company X, and asking if Company X having ISO9001 and IPC-A-610 certifications indicates that Widget A meets UL/IEC61010 -- not that he wants them to do any manufacturing of his own product. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: It becomes stricter the more regulated industry you work in. I've worked for more than a decade in medical and it's safety happy environment. Ditto for automotive. Never mind aerospace.. At the end of the day, if you have validated QA process for your medical device, it should catch any misbehaving units but it's always better to ask for the assembly standards so you can demand reparations if you get supplied substandard equipment.

Comment: So let's say, IPC-A-610 is not required to sell IEC 60950 certified equipment but if you have to take responsibility to supply safe product, don't let your supplier get away with supplying defective goods.

Comment: @Jim Same here. IEC don't care about by what standard you solder your components, as long as the end result fullfills their standard.

Comment: @Jim You are exactly right. This is what I was asking about I am not asking someone to make a custom part just trying to see if their part is compliant with the 60950 standards. I was able to find the companies "Declaration of Conformity" which contained the information I needed. Thank you to everyone for your responses

Answer (score -1):

Tl;Dr you want your PCB assembler to have ISO9001 and IPC-A-610 certificates and IPC-600 from the PCB fab. These have to do with the supplier actually supplying a product that works, you would be ultimately responsible that you've done due diligence that the product is manufactured to your specifications.

IEC60950 requires a battery of tests to show it's safe, most of which you can actually sidestep by using low voltage (e.g. 24V) external power supply that's IEC60950 rated. You also need to contend with IEC61000 series of standards on RF emissions and immunity but that's another story.

---

IEC 60950 (now superseded by IEC 62368-1) is a top level safety standard that specifies a range of requirements and tests required to put the CE mark on a product signifying it's safe to use and to sell on market.

Having a proper QA system such as ISO9001 is often part of this but not absolute requirement depending on the exact product nature. You really do want an assembler/fab to have one of these however.

IPC-A-610 is a quality standard of PCB assembly. In basic level it's a standard you can quote to the assembler and they cannot weasel out of rubbish assembly job. There are three classes, "1" is for general equipment but to my mind it's borderline functional, larger misalignments are allowed than you might expect. "2" is for Dedicated installation electronics e.g. customer access portals and the like that require some fault tolerance. This is what I'd usually ask for. Class "3" is for high reliability products, it's nice to have but often suppliers balk at this.

If the supplier does quote this, they usually also have ISO9001 in place and maybe IPC-600 if they also make the PCBs.

Comment: _"ISO9001 is often part of this but not absolute requirement"_ i.e. no such requirement. Same goes for IPC610, it has nothing to do with IEC60950.

Comment: @winny if your product fails in use, literally burning down the house, you may be in trouble if your supplier does not have a certified manufacturing process. They are not in trouble if they can show they've done due diligence as well. In essence is rear-saving excercise but results in real-life safer world.

Comment: Irrelevant for passing IEC60950 or not.

Comment: If the relevant standards for your product don't require a QMS then nobody is going to prison if your suppliers don't use one, calm down. Some do, some don't. For example, FDA requirements require ISO 13485 in additon to 9001. 60950 is all about things like creepage/clearance distances, I can't find any evidence of a QMS requirement. Is it still a good idea to have one? Absolutely.

Comment: @JoeBaker I'm well familiar with ISO 13485. In fact I'm starting a new job in a month where I'll be working with MDD / IEC 60601 3rd edition again. Good times. QMS is there to help you out when something (or someone!) goes wrong and the fingerpointing begins. And you can't flat out do medical devices without one, at least not in EU.

Comment: There's a whole mechanism of "notified bodies" to shield the manufacturers of being sued when someone dies because something went wrong with your device, but you better have your audited paper trail at the ready. A well known example is a baby monitor which didn't actually go off when the baby stopped breathing. An unfortunate interaction between public radio broadcast and the people walking around inside the house but there you are.